# jQuery get query string values then find elements that match

Tags: jquery, regex

Using a regex I am trying to extract the digit values from the query string. Then take those values and find elements in the DOM whos data-value attribute is equal to a value in the regex returned results.

**Regex**

- Need to remove allow=1 and paged=0
- Only select  value pairs with digit values

This is how my query string looks:

```
var query = location.search;
console.log(query);
//log ?allow=1&paged=0&categories=96,105,25&attr_color=14,98&promotion=monthly
```

I am hoping to have the regex return:

```
96,105,25,14,98
```

Where allow & paged are removed, and promotion is not captured because its value is not a digit.

**Searching the DOM**

Once I have those values I want to search the DOM for elements (any .list, .checkbox or .option class) who's data-value matches a value in the regex results.

Here is some sample markup of the elements that should match based off the values.

```
<div class="widget categories">
    <!-- match -->
    <a href="#" class="list" data-value="96">Pants</a>

    <!-- NO match -->
    <input class="checkbox" id="shoes" name="shoes" value="false" data-value="123"> 
    <!-- match -->
    <input class="checkbox" id="shirts" name="shirts" value="true" data-value="105"> 

    <select name="cat" id="cat">
        <option selected="selected" value="">All Categories</option>
        <!-- match -->
        <option class="option" value="25" data-value="25">Shoes</option>
        <!-- NO match -->
        <option class="option" value="22" data-value="22">Jackets</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="widget attribute-color">
    <!-- NO match -->
    <a href="#" class="list" data-value="55">Blue</a>

    <!-- match -->
    <input class="checkbox" id="purple" name="purple" value="true" data-value="14"> 

    <select name="colors" id="colors">
        <option selected="selected" value="">All Colors</option>
        <!-- NO match -->
        <option class="option" value="112" data-value="112">Red</option>
        <!--match -->
        <option class="option" value="98" data-value="98">Yellow</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Edit**

I am having issues using RegExp.

If I use this it returns null

```
var regexS = "allow=\d+|paged=\d+|(\d+)(?=,|&)";
var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
var query = regex.exec( location.search );
console.log("query: " + query); // query: null
```

If I use this it only returns I believe the first result

```
var query = /allow=\d+|paged=\d+|(\d+)(?=,|&)/g.exec( location.search );
console.log("query: " + query); // query: 1,1
```

**Edit 2**

To handle the regex I ended up using .replace() instead of new RegExp (couldn't get that to work not sure why.)

```
var query  = location.search;
var values = '';

query.replace(/allow=\d+|paged=\d+|(\d+)(?=,|&)/g, function(param, match) {
    if (match != undefined) {
        values += match + ',';
    };
});
console.log("values: " + values); // values: 96,105,25,14
```

The problem I am now having is it never returns the last number of the query string, so **98** is omitted from the matched results.

The strange part is if I use an actual **string** instead of **location.search** it does return the last number:

```
var query = '?allow=1&paged=0&categories=96,105,25&attr_color=14,98&promotion=monthly';
console.log("values: " + values); // values: 96,105,25,14,98
```

I have tried using **var query = location.search.toString()**; and **JSON.stringify(location.search)** but the last digit is always omitted.

I am so close to having this figured out any help is much appreciated.

Comment: why `48` was not selected

Comment: sorry 48 has been removed

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have comma separated values `"96,105,25,14,98,48"`. Use:

```
var colorncategories= "96,105,25,14,98,48".split(",");
var elem_colorncategories= $("[data-value='" + colorncategories.join("'],[data-value='") + "']");
```

Comment: Unfortunately no I really need help with the regex portion of the answer been trying for 2 days to figure it out.

Comment: This worked perfectly for the second part of the question "Searching the DOM". Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
allow=\d+|paged=\d+|(\d+)(?=,|&)
```

Try this.Grab the matches.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/67

Comment: Seems to be grabbing allow and paged, is there a way to negate these so they are not matched? Also having issues using RegExp, see edited question above. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @George as you can see in demo....the allow and pageid are not in groups.are we understadning the qestion worng?

Comment: @George use match.groups. dont use search

Comment: No I think you understand the question correctly. What was confusing to me was on the link you provided it showed allow and paged matching in the "Substitution" Field but I can see in the "Match Information" that the correct values are matched (96,105,25,14,98). However I am having trouble implementing this Regex in jQuery, see my edited answer. What did you mean by "use match.groups" not "search"?